# Add new tag "vdo"?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I do not have enough reputation to create a new tag on this site, therefore I propose to add the tag here. Hope this is the right (or at least not very wrong) approach.

> The Virtual Data Optimizer (VDO) feature provides inline block-level deduplication, compression, and thin provisioning for storage. You can manage VDO as a type of LVM logical volumes (LVs), similar to LVM thinly provisioned volumes. -- [Red Hat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/9-beta/html/deduplicating_and_compressing_logical_volumes_on_rhel/introduction-to-vdo-on-lvm_deduplicating-and-compressing-logical-volumes-on-rhel)

Comment: You need a question to which the tag can be added. Please list some questions which are about VDOs, and please also explain why it needs a new tag and can't fit in existing tags.

Comment: What muru said. Are there actually any questions that need this tag? Also, yes, this is absolutely the right approach, and thank you!

Comment: @terdon, [a search on the main site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=vdo) reveals a few candidates.

Answer (score 2):

As this is a new feature of RHEL, I'm in support of this idea. terdon's comment has the right sequence, though:

1. ask question (with existing tags)
2. ensure question(s) don't get deleted
3. add vdo tag to questions as appropriate

This might be a good time to think about what the vdo tag excerpt and wiki would say on U&L.